# Callback in JAX fori_loop

Tags: jax

Is it possible to have callbacks inside a function passed to JAX `fori_loop`?

In my case, the callback will save to disk some of the intermediate results produced in the function.

I tried something like this:

```py
def callback(values):
  # do something

def diffusion_loop(i, args):
  # do something
  callback(results)
  return results

final_result, _ = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, num_steps, diffusion_loop, (arg1, arg2))
```

But then if I use `final_result` or whatever was saved from the `callback` I get an error like this

```py
UnfilteredStackTrace: jax._src.errors.UnexpectedTracerError: Encountered an unexpected tracer. A function transformed by JAX had a side effect, allowing for a reference to an intermediate value with type float32[1,4,64,64] wrapped in a DynamicJaxprTracer to escape the scope of the transformation.
JAX transformations require that functions explicitly return their outputs, and disallow saving intermediate values to global state.
The function being traced when the value leaked was scanned_fun at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/jax/_src/lax/control_flow/loops.py:1606 traced for scan.
------------------------------
The leaked intermediate value was created on line /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/diffusers/schedulers/scheduling_pndm_flax.py:508 (_get_prev_sample). 
------------------------------
When the value was created, the final 5 stack frames (most recent last) excluding JAX-internal frames were:
------------------------------
<timed exec>:81 (<module>)
<timed exec>:67 (diffusion_loop)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/diffusers/schedulers/scheduling_pndm_flax.py:264 (step)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/diffusers/schedulers/scheduling_pndm_flax.py:472 (step_plms)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/diffusers/schedulers/scheduling_pndm_flax.py:508 (_get_prev_sample)
------------------------------

To catch the leak earlier, try setting the environment variable JAX_CHECK_TRACER_LEAKS or using the `jax.checking_leaks` context manager.
See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.UnexpectedTracerError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do a callback to the host that is impure (i.e. it has a side-effect of saving values to disk) and does not return any values to the runtime. For that, one option is `jax.experimental.host_callback.id_tap`, discussed in the docs [here](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.experimental.host_callback.html#using-id-tap-to-call-a-python-function-on-the-host-with-no-returned-values).

For example:

```py
import jax
from jax.experimental import host_callback as hcb

def callback(value, transforms):
  # do something
  print(f"callback: {value}")

def diffusion_loop(i, args):
  hcb.id_tap(callback, i)
  return args

args = (1, 2)
result, _ = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, 5, diffusion_loop, args)
```

```
callback: 0
callback: 1
callback: 2
callback: 3
callback: 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I end up doing it in simple python loop, will try to use this host_callback. I wonder if I can also return the intermediate result that will be used in the next iteration? cause from the error jax does not seem to like doing anything with this graph of results

Comment: It’s not clear what intermediate result or what error you’re talking about

Comment: so inside the loop function i do calculate some results that get passed to next iteration in the args, I also want to use those intermediate results and pass them to a callback function like I was trying to do earlier

Comment: The result returned from the body function is passed to the body function in the next iteration. If that doesn’t answer your question, I’d suggest making a new post. It’s hard to ask and answer follow-ups effectively in comment threads.